# beginSheetForDirectory ... Deprecated

Tags: objective-c, modal-dialog, deprecated

I have following code which works fine, however when I updated to Lion I started getting warnings that this method has been deprecated and suggests that I use "beginSheetModalforWindow".  How would you translate the following to code to use that?

```
[savePanel beginSheetForDirectory: NULL
                                 file: fileName
                       modalForWindow: mWindow
                        modalDelegate: self
                       didEndSelector: @selector(savePanelDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) 
                          contextInfo: NULL];
```

Comment: Maybe http://pastie.org/2314089 ? I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:`, and you'd do something like this:

```
[savePanel setNameFieldStringValue:fileName];
[savePanel beginSheetModelForWindow:mWindow completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        // do the save
    }
}];
```